# mysql distort my serialize data which make is invalid

Tags: php, mysql

I am writing an application using php mysql where I upload multiple files at once

I serialize my data before uploading it to mysql but mysql distort the data at the end which renders the data invalid

If I upload 1-4 files everything works fine but if I upload more than 4 files I get error when trying to view the files(images/files)

when I upload 2 files the serialized data looks like this

```
a:2:{i:0;s:22:"uploads/HqihCeKwvR.png";i:1;s:22:"uploads/cQqshZLoNB.png";}
```

but if I upload more than 4 files the serialized data looks like this

```
a:8:{i:0;s:22:"uploads/nQEOmDelCR.png";i:1;s:22:"uploads/qMCJaNsSPl.png";i:2;s:22:"uploads/W0oUaN3GZm.png";i:3;s:22:"uploads/qJEYRkh04I.png";i:4;s:22:"uploads/h1SozRvFZV.png";i:5;s:22:"uploads/bPcJ32yWuC.png";i:6;s:22:"uploads/OURS3jCzIp.jpg";i:7;s:22:"up
```

Upload.php

```
$qualification = multiple_upload($_FILES["qualification"]);

function multiple_upload($file)
{

    $target_dir = "uploads/";
    $uploadOk = 1;

    $countfiles  = count($_FILES['qualification']['name']);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $countfiles; $i++) {
        $file_name = generateRandomString();
        $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES['qualification']['name'][$i]);

        $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
        $file_path = $target_dir . "" . $file_name . "." . $imageFileType;

        $qualifications[] = $file_path;
        // Allow certain file formats

        if (
            $imageFileType != "jpg" || $imageFileType != "png" || $imageFileType != "jpeg" || $imageFileType != "pdf" || $imageFileType != "doc" || $imageFileType != "docx"
            || $imageFileType != "gif"
        ) {
            $imageFileType = $imageFileType;
        } else {
            die("Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.");
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }

        // echo $_FILES['qualification']['name'][$key] . "<br />";
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['qualification']['tmp_name'][$i], $file_path)) {
            // echo "The file " . htmlspecialchars(basename($file["name"])) . " has been uploaded.";
            echo $file_path;
        } else {
            // die("Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.");
        }
    }
    return serialize($qualifications);
}

function generateRandomString($length = 10)
{
    return substr(str_shuffle(str_repeat($x = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', ceil($length / strlen($x)))), 1, $length);
}

 $sql = "
      INSERT INTO 
          staff_info 
        SET 
          qualification = '$qualification '";


 if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "successful...";
    // header("location: upload_successful.html");
  } else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
  }
```

View.php

```
 <?php
    $qualifications = unserialize($row["qualification"]);
    foreach ($qualifications as $key => $value) {
        echo '<img src="' . $value . '" style="width: 300px; height: 300px; object-fit:cover" alt=""> <br />';
    }
      ?>
```

How do I tackle this problem?

Comment: Make sure that the field is long enough. It looks like your string is about 256 characters long, so you've hit the limit of the field. Try changing the field to a [blob or text field](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/blob.html) instead, or just make the field larger. Or normalize your database so that each image is one entry in another table.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](https://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: A) Field is insufficiently long, it's being truncated. B) You are creating a SQL injection conflict on the quotes.

Comment: @aynber I used text field an I am getting the same error